# External Content Type creating problems in Saving Site as Template on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, external-content-type

I'm having trouble trying to save a SharePoint 2010 site as template.

> SPSolutionExporter: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Feature
>   definition with Id a4fbae30-a689-43d0-8f75-484a940336cf failed
>   validation, file
>   'SE_Delivery_template_20131004ListInstances\ElementsFields.xml', line
>   581, character 364: The 'EntityName' attribute is not allowed.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.SolutionFile.FeatureXmlValidationCallBack(Object
>   sender, ValidationEventArgs evtargs)     at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code,
>   String arg)     at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateAttribute(String lName,
>   String ns, XmlValueGetter attributeValueGetter, String
>   attributeStringValue, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo)     at
>   System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ValidateAttributes()     at
>   System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()     at
>   System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()     at
>   System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()     at
>   System.Xml.XmlReader.IsStartElement()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.XsdValidateXml(XmlTextReader
>   xmlStreamReader, String friendlyName, String pathXsdFile, String
>   tagExpectedRootNode, ValidationEventHandler xsdValEventHandler)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.SolutionFile.ValidateFeatureXmlFile(String
>   rootTagElement)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.AddFeatureElementsCore(XmlNodeList
>   nodeList, String strFeatureDirRelativeToCabFile, Guid featureId,
>   Dictionary`2 filesAdded)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.AddFeatureElements(XmlNode
>   root, String strFeatureDirRelativeToCabFile, String
>   strFeatureXmlFilename, Guid featureId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.WspSolutionFeature.ProcessFeatureXml()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.InitSolutionFeatures(XmlNode
>   root)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.ProcessSolutionManifest()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.Load()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.CreateSolutionPackage(SPRequest
>   request, String name, String signature, Byte[] fileBytes)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.AddOrUpgrade(SPListItem
>   item, SPUserSolution existingSolution)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.Add(Int32
>   solutionGalleryItemId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web,
>   String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode
>   exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String workflowTemplateName,
>   String destinationListUrl)

When I look into the Solution Galleries, I can see the wsp file there. When I try to activate it, I get the following error:

> Feature definition with Id ab614de8-41e0-4ad2-93da-49daf51285d3 failed
>   validation, file
>   'SE_Delivery_template_20131004ListInstances\ElementsFields.xml', line
>   581, character 364: The 'EntityName' attribute is not allowed.

So I downloaded this wsp file to take a look inside it and

```
<Field Type="BusinessData" DisplayName="ES Projects" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Group="IMS" ID="{27a81718-4feb-4369-acde-0af56ae760cb}" SourceID="{952e3e98-3e76-4b93-8f3f-ad4b6725d71a}" StaticName="ES_x0020_Projects" Name="ES_x0020_Projects" SystemInstance="dbName" EntityNamespace="http://spSite/assets" EntityName="ESProjectList" BdcField="ProjectNumber_And_Name" Profile="" HasActions="True" SecondaryFieldBdcNames="0" RelatedField="ESProjectList_ID" SecondaryFieldWssNames="0" RelatedFieldBDCField="" RelatedFieldWssStaticName="ESProjectList_ID" SecondaryFieldsWssStaticNames="0" AddFieldOption="AddFieldInternalNameHint" Overwrite="TRUE" />
```

This is an External Content Type that I had used. Thing is, that it's just part of the site since it is inheriting it from the parent site and we may want to use it in the future. This is a site column actually.

So now I'm stuck with this, since I cannot create a modified version of the Site Template because of this error. Could you please give me some tips & tricks to solve this?

Kind regards,
Imran

Comment: you may have to edit the elements xml file was mentioned here: http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2013/05/06/fixing-an-invalid-bcs-column-in-a-list-template/

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the custom feature with ID of `038ab85a-fb82-457d-ba1d-062741085d82`? Are you sure there are no custom global solutions/template changes which get rolled out to your team site.

Comment: This ID is not there in the text I mentioned Falak. Could you check that again please.

Comment: It turns out that a `EntityName`attribute is an external data or BCS column that is causing the problem. You need to investigate the contents of the WSP file deploying it.